# Script tag inside iframe executes on parent dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I write jQuery script inside my iframe to hide h1 inside the iframe

```
<iframe id = "preview" width="800" height="500">   
</iframe>

 <script>
var H = "<html><head><script>$(\'#hh\').toggle();<";
H+= "/script></head><body><h1 id='hh'>JavaScript</h1></body></html>";

 var previewFrame = document.getElementById("preview");
 var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
 preview.open();
 preview.write(H);
 preview.close();
  </script>
```

but,the script can't see the elements inside the iframe. when I moved the element with id='hh' out of the iframe, the script works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use jQuery inside the iframe for the script you're putting in the iframe, but you don't have jQuery in the iframe.  The iframe is a whole different execution context.  If you want to use jQuery in there, you have to load jQuery in there.

Also, you can't run a script that tries to modify the DOM from the `<head>` element.  The DOM isn't loaded yet.  You have to either move that script after the content in the `<body>` (e.g. right before `</body>`) or use `$(document).ready(...)` to run the script AFTER the DOM is ready.

OK, this is the sum of issues I found:

1. You need jQuery in the iframe if you're going to use it there.
2. You must use a separate `<script>` tag for loading jQuery.  You can't use both a `.src` and a inline script in the same tag.
3. You must use the proper `$(document).ready(function() { your code here})` syntax.
4. You must break apart the `<script>` and `</script>` that is in your JS string so the browser doesn't interpret it like `'<scr'` + `'ipt>'`.

This works for me:

```
var H = '<html><body><h1 id="hh">JavaScript</h1>';
H += '<scr' + 'ipt src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>';
H += '<scr' + 'ipt>$(document).ready(function() {';
H += '$("#hh").hide();';
H += '});</scr' + 'ipt>';
H += '</body></html>';

var previewFrame = document.getElementById("preview");
var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
preview.open();
preview.write(H);
preview.close();
```

I've broken up your `H` variable to make it more readable and easier to spot errors.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8L3KT/

---

FYI, this is the painful way to do this.  Creating a full HTML document in JS is easy to make mistakes with.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't works,in addition it works when the script hide a h1 outside the iframe

Comment: i did load it and the same thing happens

Comment: @MuhammadSultan - see the additional issue I added to my answer.

Comment: I did this:
var H = "<html><body><h1 id='hh'>JavaScript</h1><script src=\"js/jquery-1.10.2.js\">$document.ready($(\'#hh\').hide(););<";
 H+= "/script></body></html>"
but it doesn't work too

Comment: @MuhammadSultan - your script tags are messed up.  The `<script>` tag that loads jQuery must be it's own script tag.  If you have a `src=xxx` on the `<script>` tag, then you can't have content in the script tag.  So, you will need two `<script>` tags, one to load jQuery and one to run your script in.

Comment: @MuhammadSultan - and it's `$(document).ready(function() {your code here})`, not what you have.

Comment: @MuhammadSultan - Working code and demo added to my answer.  Also have to break up your `<script>` tags.

Comment: thanks very much,it did work,but what is the non painful way to do it please?

Comment: @MuhammadSultan - Much less painful to just put the content and scripts in the iframe as another other HTML document.  Or put it in another HTML document and reference it with `src=xxx.html` in the iframe tag.  Or just dynamically add content to the exist iframe document without writing a whole new one.